# Can we merge multiple attachments(content document) to a single attachment

Tags: contentdocument

Hi our users will be uploading different attachments through mobile (generally different pages of same file).  we have a requirement where we need to merge those multiple attachments to single attachment (say like a pdf of all the pages). Is there a way we can do it?

Comment: One of the approach could be to use third-party tool to merge and convert documents (since it require a lot of calculations so would hit CPU limit in apex)

Comment: Thanks for the input @kurunve. Can you suggest any tool that does this?

Comment: Have you looked at AppExchange?